# Problema con acumulador en Java

Tags: botón, jtextfield

Es la primera vez que solicitu su ayuda, estoy haciendo este código como tarea y no he logrado que el acumulador "totaldia" guarde los datos que le manda la variable "Apagar". Agradecería mucho si me hacen ver donde fallo. Gracias.

```
package pupuseria_la_ansiedad;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Pupuseria_La_Ansiedad extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JLabel bienvenida, indicacion, pupusas1, pupusas2, pupusas3, orden, venta;
        JTextField pupas1, pupas2, pupas3;
        JLabel pago, total;


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pupusas La Ansiedad");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 350);

        JPanel entradaPanel = new JPanel();
        entradaPanel.setBounds(40,20,300,50);
        bienvenida = new JLabel("SISTEMA DE 'PUPUSERIA LA ANSIEDAD'", JLabel.CENTER);
        entradaPanel.add(bienvenida);
        indicacion = new JLabel("INGRESE CANTIDAD DE PUPUSAS", JLabel.CENTER);
        entradaPanel.add(indicacion);

        JPanel pupusasPanel = new JPanel();
        pupusasPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        pupusasPanel.setBounds(40,80,220,100);
        pupusas1 = new JLabel("Revueltas y Frijol con Queso");
        pupusas1.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        pupusasPanel.add(pupusas1);
        pupusas2 = new JLabel("Queso y Chicharron con Queso");
        pupusas2.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        pupusasPanel.add(pupusas2);
        pupusas3 = new JLabel("Especialidad");
        pupusas3.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        pupusasPanel.add(pupusas3);

        JPanel cantidadPanel = new JPanel();
        cantidadPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        cantidadPanel.setBounds(270,80,70,100);
        pupas1 = new JTextField("");
        pupas1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        cantidadPanel.add(pupas1);
        pupas2 = new JTextField("");
        pupas2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        cantidadPanel.add(pupas2);
        pupas3 = new JTextField("");
        pupas3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        cantidadPanel.add(pupas3);

        JPanel botonPanel = new JPanel();
        botonPanel.setBounds(60,200,120,50);
        JButton botonOrdenar=new JButton("Enviar Orden");
        botonPanel.add(botonOrdenar);

        JPanel boton2Panel = new JPanel();
        boton2Panel.setBounds(200,200,120,50);
        JButton botonLimpiar=new JButton("Limpiar Orden");
        boton2Panel.add(botonLimpiar);


        JPanel ordenPanel = new JPanel();
        ordenPanel.setBounds(40,250,90,40);
        orden = new JLabel("Esta Orden:");
        orden.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        ordenPanel.add(orden);

        JPanel pagoPanel = new JPanel();
        pagoPanel.setBounds(130,250,50,40);
        pago = new JLabel("");
        pago.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        pagoPanel.add(pago);

        JPanel ventaPanel = new JPanel();
        ventaPanel.setBounds(200,250,80,40);
        venta = new JLabel("Total Día:");
        venta.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        ventaPanel.add(venta);

        JPanel totalPanel = new JPanel();
        totalPanel.setBounds(270,250,80,40);
        total = new JLabel();
        total.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        totalPanel.add(total);

        //Agregar elementos al frame
        Container contenedor=frame.getContentPane();
        contenedor.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(pupusasPanel);
        frame.add(entradaPanel);
        frame.add(cantidadPanel);
        frame.add(botonPanel);
        frame.add(boton2Panel);
        frame.add(ordenPanel);
        frame.add(pagoPanel);
        frame.add(ventaPanel);
        frame.add(totalPanel);

        botonOrdenar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                int p1, p2, p3;
                double totaldia = 0;

                if(pupas1.getText().length()==0){
                    p1=0;
                }
                else{
                    p1= Integer.parseInt(pupas1.getText());
                }

                if(pupas2.getText().length()==0){
                    p2=0;
                }
                else{
                    p2= Integer.parseInt(pupas2.getText());
                }

                if(pupas3.getText().length()==0){
                    p3=0;
                }
                else{
                    p3= Integer.parseInt(pupas3.getText());
                }

                double Apagar = ((p1*0.50)+(p2*0.55)+(p3*0.75));
                pago.setText("$"+Apagar);

                totaldia = totaldia+Apagar;

                total.setText("$"+totaldia);

                pupas1.setText("");
                pupas2.setText("");
                pupas3.setText("");
            }
        });

        botonLimpiar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               pago.setText("");
                //total.setText("");
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que se llama al método actionPerformed se crea e inicializa a cero la variable totaldia.  Si lo que quieres es que cada vez que se llama a dicho método se actualize totaldía debes hacer una pequeña trampa, crear una clase dedicada solo a contener el valor de totaldia. Algo así:

```
public class Totaldia {
private double total;
public Totaldia(double total) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.total = total;
}
public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}
public void setTotal(double total) {
    this.total = total;
}

}
```

Entonces utilizar una instancia final de la clase Totaldia en lugar de tu variable primitiva double.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Pupuseria_La_Ansiedad extends JFrame {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    JLabel bienvenida, indicacion, pupusas1, pupusas2, pupusas3, orden, venta;
    JTextField pupas1, pupas2, pupas3;
    JLabel pago, total;
    final Totaldia totaldia = new Totaldia(0);


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pupusas La Ansiedad");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 350);

    JPanel entradaPanel = new JPanel();
    entradaPanel.setBounds(40,20,300,50);
    bienvenida = new JLabel("SISTEMA DE 'PUPUSERIA LA ANSIEDAD'", JLabel.CENTER);
    entradaPanel.add(bienvenida);
    indicacion = new JLabel("INGRESE CANTIDAD DE PUPUSAS", JLabel.CENTER);
    entradaPanel.add(indicacion);

    JPanel pupusasPanel = new JPanel();
    pupusasPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    pupusasPanel.setBounds(40,80,220,100);
    pupusas1 = new JLabel("Revueltas y Frijol con Queso");
    pupusas1.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
    pupusasPanel.add(pupusas1);
    pupusas2 = new JLabel("Queso y Chicharron con Queso");
    pupusas2.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
    pupusasPanel.add(pupusas2);
    pupusas3 = new JLabel("Especialidad");
    pupusas3.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
    pupusasPanel.add(pupusas3);

    JPanel cantidadPanel = new JPanel();
    cantidadPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    cantidadPanel.setBounds(270,80,70,100);
    pupas1 = new JTextField("");
    pupas1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    cantidadPanel.add(pupas1);
    pupas2 = new JTextField("");
    pupas2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    cantidadPanel.add(pupas2);
    pupas3 = new JTextField("");
    pupas3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    cantidadPanel.add(pupas3);

    JPanel botonPanel = new JPanel();
    botonPanel.setBounds(60,200,120,50);
    JButton botonOrdenar=new JButton("Enviar Orden");
    botonPanel.add(botonOrdenar);

    JPanel boton2Panel = new JPanel();
    boton2Panel.setBounds(200,200,120,50);
    JButton botonLimpiar=new JButton("Limpiar Orden");
    boton2Panel.add(botonLimpiar);


    JPanel ordenPanel = new JPanel();
    ordenPanel.setBounds(40,250,90,40);
    orden = new JLabel("Esta Orden:");
    orden.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
    ordenPanel.add(orden);

    JPanel pagoPanel = new JPanel();
    pagoPanel.setBounds(130,250,50,40);
    pago = new JLabel("");
    pago.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
    pagoPanel.add(pago);

    JPanel ventaPanel = new JPanel();
    ventaPanel.setBounds(200,250,80,40);
    venta = new JLabel("Total Día:");
    venta.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
    ventaPanel.add(venta);

    JPanel totalPanel = new JPanel();
    totalPanel.setBounds(270,250,80,40);
    total = new JLabel();
    total.setFont(new Font ("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
    totalPanel.add(total);

    //Agregar elementos al frame
    Container contenedor=frame.getContentPane();
    contenedor.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(pupusasPanel);
    frame.add(entradaPanel);
    frame.add(cantidadPanel);
    frame.add(botonPanel);
    frame.add(boton2Panel);
    frame.add(ordenPanel);
    frame.add(pagoPanel);
    frame.add(ventaPanel);
    frame.add(totalPanel);

    botonOrdenar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            int p1, p2, p3;


            if(pupas1.getText().length()==0){
                p1=0;
            }
            else{
                p1= Integer.parseInt(pupas1.getText());
            }

            if(pupas2.getText().length()==0){
                p2=0;
            }
            else{
                p2= Integer.parseInt(pupas2.getText());
            }

            if(pupas3.getText().length()==0){
                p3=0;
            }
            else{
                p3= Integer.parseInt(pupas3.getText());
            }

            double Apagar = ((p1*0.50)+(p2*0.55)+(p3*0.75));
            pago.setText("$"+Apagar);


            totaldia.setTotal(totaldia.getTotal()+Apagar);

            total.setText("$"+totaldia);

            pupas1.setText("");
            pupas2.setText("");
            pupas3.setText("");
        }
    });

    botonLimpiar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           pago.setText("");
            //total.setText("");
        }
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Espero que te sirva .

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta tan pronta, hice el cambio de ubicación de la declaración de la variable, pero ahora me arroja un error donde la misma entra en función. ¿Hay algo que pueda hacer para corregir eso?

Comment: Que error? Saludos

Comment: Este: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

Comment: Disculpa el despiste. Mira la respuesta editada. Saludos

Comment: David, agradezco mucho tu ayuda. Ha quedado muy bien. El único error que aún me arroja es que al agregar en lo JTextField un dato múltiplo de 3, agrega al resultado muchos decimales. Saludos.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido de ayuda

Comment: Has probado String.format?